test for differences in empirical cumulative distribution functions between groups
What test could I use to test for differences in empirical cumulative distribution functions between two or more groups? Note that I am not looking for a test two compare two ecdf (Kolmogorov–Smirnov test for instance), but two/several groups in which there are several samples each with their own ecdf.
For instance, in the image below, is there a significant difference between the two groups, each containing three samples? Additional question : do the groups differ on the entire ecdf curve or only on part of it, and if so, which part?

